# How to filter data in columns using google app script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm facing some issues related to filter data in the columns using google app script editor.

[image]

I'm able to set a filter in columns using google app script as you can see in the above screenshot. but problem is when I'm trying to get the filtered data. it returns some number series instead of actual data as you can see below :

```
[20-03-09 18:19:48:395 IST] [1,2,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,30]
```

**To set a filter :**

```
function setFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var filterSettings = {};

  // The range of data on which you want to apply the filter.
  // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
  filterSettings.range = {
    sheetId: ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  };

  // Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter
  // https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria
  filterSettings.criteria = {};
  var columnIndex = 2;
  filterSettings['criteria'][columnIndex] = {
    'hiddenValues': ["England", "France"]
  };

  var request = {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": filterSettings
    }
  };
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': [request]}, ss.getId());
}
```

**To get the filtered data:**

```
function getFilteredRows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var sheetId = ss.getActiveSheet().getSheetId();
  let data = getIndexesOfFilteredRows(ssId,sheetId);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
}

function getIndexesOfFilteredRows(ssId, sheetId) {
  var hiddenRows = [];

  // limit what's returned from the API
  var fields = "sheets(data(rowMetadata(hiddenByFilter)),properties/sheetId)";
  var sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {fields: fields}).sheets;  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].properties.sheetId == sheetId) {
      var data = sheets[i].data;
      var rows = data[0].rowMetadata;
      for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        if (rows[j].hiddenByFilter) hiddenRows.push(j);
      }
    }
  }
  return hiddenRows;
}
```

How to set a filter in columns and get the filtered data using google app script.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your case, the script for filtering has already worked. You want the script for retrieving the values from the filtered sheet in the Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Sheets API with Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

In your case, the function of `getIndexesOfFilteredRows` is modified. Using `hiddenByFilter`, the hidden rows and shown rows are retrieved as an object.

#### Modified script:

```
function getIndexesOfFilteredRows(ssId, sheetId) {
  var object = {hiddenRows: [], hiddenRowValues: [], shownRows: [], shownRowValues: []};

  // limit what's returned from the API
  var fields = "sheets(data,properties/sheetId)";
  var sheets = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {fields: fields}).sheets;  
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].properties.sheetId == sheetId) {
      var data = sheets[i].data;
      var rows = data[0].rowMetadata;
      for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
        var r = [];
        if (data[0].rowData[j] && Array.isArray(data[0].rowData[j].values)) {
          r = data[0].rowData[j].values.map(function(e) {
            var temp = "";
            if (e.hasOwnProperty("userEnteredValue")) {
              if (e.userEnteredValue.hasOwnProperty("numberValue")) {
                temp = e.userEnteredValue.numberValue;
              } else if (e.userEnteredValue.hasOwnProperty("stringValue")) {
                temp = e.userEnteredValue.stringValue;
              }
            }
            return temp;
          });
        }
        if (r.length > 0) {
          if (rows[j].hiddenByFilter) {
            object.hiddenRows.push(j);
            object.hiddenRowValues.push(r);
          } else {
            object.shownRows.push(j);
            object.shownRowValues.push(r);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return object;
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is run for the filtered sheet, the following object which has the hidden row numbers, hidden row values, shown row numbers and shown row values is returned.

```
{
    "hiddenRows":[0,1],
    "hiddenRowValues":[["a1","b1","c1"],["a2","b2","c2"]],
    "shownRows":[2,3],
    "shownRowValues":[["a3","b3","c3"],["a4","b4","c4"]]
}
```

#### Reference:

- [DimensionProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#dimensionproperties)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

### Added:

How about this sample script? In this sample script, the values filtered with `filterValues` can be retrieved as an object. In this case, the result is the same with your `setFilter()` and the modified `getIndexesOfFilteredRows()`. But the basic filter is not used. So please be careful this.

```
function myFunction() {
  var filterValues = ["England", "France"]; // Please set the filter values.
  var column = 3; // In this case, it's the column "C". Please set the column number.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var object = values.reduce(function(o, e, i) {
    if (filterValues.indexOf(e[column - 1]) > -1) {
      o.hiddenRows.push(i + 1);
      o.hiddenRowValues.push(e);
    } else {
      o.shownRows.push(i + 1);
      o.shownRowValues.push(e);
    }
    return o;
  }, {hiddenRows: [], hiddenRowValues: [], shownRows: [], shownRowValues: []});

  Logger.log(object)
}
```

- If you want to retrieve only the filtered values, this script might be suitable.
- In this case, the script can run with and without V8. But when V8 is enabled, the loop speed will be fast. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/3331e1e631d619abef8f32c4be14ba3a)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Tanaike. I will try this out. Main idea is to filter the data from a "Sheet" in an efficient manner, we tried iterating through all the data and then returning the response, it works; but its very slow. Will try this solution and update you.

Comment: @Chetan Sachdev Thank you for replying. From your replying, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for your quick reply. I have tested the first script and It's working as expected and Will check the second script.
Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Tanaike While running the second script... Getting below error :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDataRange' of null (line 140, file "filter")

To run the script, I have figure out the solution and tested the script. 
It's working and has updated the above script with the one-line change.

Comment: @Vaibhav Bhuva Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I would like to use this second function but can not figure out how to get only the `shownRowValues` as an array